# retrieve last 5 unread messages

Tags: javascript, jquery, gmail, gmail-api

I'm trying to use the GMAIL API with javascript to retrieve the unread messages from a users' inbox. At most the last 5.

I'm trying to use jQuery's `$.get` after the user has logged in with the G+ api, but I am getting a 404 error in the console.

Here is what I am running: `$.get('https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/', function(data){ console.log(data); });` I haven't tried limiting the messages to unread or 5 at most as, for now, I am currently unable to even retrieve any.

How do I get the unread messages in a users' inbox, at most 5, or even get the messages in the current logged in users' inbox?

**I want to figure out how to get the JSON from the API. I can parse it myself, but what requests to send ( how to get the users' id and thread id ) and then get the JSON.**
Please help me figure out how I can view the JSON in the browser or console, from there I am fine.

Comment: Have you authenticated your session before trying to actually use the API?

Comment: @Stormie I have only logged in using the G+ api in javascript. Is there more I need to do?

Comment: There isn't actually any bindings (by Google) for JavaScript, there are for [Java, Python and .net](https://developers.google.com/gmail/). I could provide a solution in those languages, but not in JavaScript.

Comment: @Stormie But the code return JSON, which I can parse with javascript / jquery. So can't I just translate it to use the get and post requests with jQuery's $.get and $.post ?

Comment: I won't be able to help you all that malark then, it'd be worth editing your question to include the `json` tag :)

Comment: @Stormie Thank you for replying. I don't need help sorting out the JSON, but I just need help knowing what calls to make with the get and post requests? if I can view the json in the browser or console, I am fine from there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently there is no JavaScript quickstart in the Gmail API documentation, but something like this should get you started, it lists the first page of threads from the user's inbox. Remember to replace YOUR_CLIENT_ID with your actual client id from the developer console.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var CLIENT_ID = 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID';
      var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'];
      var USER = 'me';

      /**
       * Called when the client library is loaded to start the auth flow.
       */
      function handleClientLoad() {
        window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);
      }

      /**
       * Check if the current user has authorized the application.
       */
      function checkAuth() {
        gapi.auth.authorize(
            {'client_id': CLIENT_ID, 'scope': SCOPES, 'immediate': true},
            handleAuthResult);
      }

      /**
       * Called when authorization server replies.
       *
       * @param {Object} authResult Authorization result.
       */
      function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
        var authButton = document.getElementById('authorizeButton');
        var outputNotice = document.getElementById('notice');
        authButton.style.display = 'none';
        outputNotice.style.display = 'block';
        if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
          // Access token has been successfully retrieved, requests can be sent to the API.
          gapi.client.load('gmail', 'v1', function() {
            listThreads(USER, function(resp) {
              var threads = resp.threads;
              for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
                var thread = threads[i];
                console.log(thread);
                console.log(thread['id']);
              }
            });
          });
        } else {
          // No access token could be retrieved, show the button to start the authorization flow.
          authButton.style.display = 'block';
          outputNotice.style.display = 'none';
          authButton.onclick = function() {
              gapi.auth.authorize(
                  {'client_id': CLIENT_ID, 'scope': SCOPES, 'immediate': false},
                  handleAuthResult);
          };
        }
      }


      /**
       * Get a page of Threads.
       *
       * @param  {String} userId User's email address. The special value 'me'
       * can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
       * @param  {Function} callback Function called when request is complete.
       */
      function listThreads(userId, callback) {
        var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.threads.list({
          'userId': userId
        });
        request.execute(callback);
      }

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" id="authorizeButton" style="display: none" value="Authorize" />
    <p id="notice" style="display: none">check browser console for output</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but in the console, I am not getting the email messages? The output in the console looks like so: `Object \n
historyId: "4414613" \n id: "147dd2015d281d8f" \n snippet: "" \n __proto__: \n Object \n 147dd2015d281d8f \n Object \n 147b4020916928f0`

shouldn't the messages or at least part of them be in snippet?

Comment: I would greatly appreciate it if you could help me. Here is a live example so you can check the console output yourself: http://irfandesign.com/gmail.html

Comment: The threads.list method only returns the historyId and id of each thread. You must use threads.get to get more detailed response. Currently threads.list has an empty snippet field, this field may be used or even removed in the future so for now don't depend on it.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your help. If you can help me figure this out, i'd gladly set a bounty and give it to you. I am getting a 400 error "'id required'" when I `console.log` the response for `gapi.client.gmail.users.threads.get`. Do I need to get the id for the thread using `gapi.client.gmail.users.theads.list` and then pass that to threads.get ? Just in the options of the request? If not, how do I do this? Please mention me in a comment so I get a notification when if, I hope, you reply.

Comment: @user3743069 you are correct, the usual flow would be calling threads.list, then use the thread id from the response to call with threads.get. when making the threads.get call you need both the userId and the id of the thread. Check the docs for more details

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/get

Comment: okay, I did exactly what I thought it was and you agreed it was. I got the id's, but when I try to pass the ids to therads.get, I get no response in the console. my code is here: http://irfanknow.com/gmail.html

Comment: started the bounty. Thanks for the help you've give me so far and in Advance!